# ADODB Only Works on Local Computer

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, adodb

Thank you for your help David.  I made the changes based on the links you suggested.  Have I missed anything, because I am still getting the same message

```
  [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
```

[I enabled "Yes" on IP5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1zyb.png)

[I also added a new inbound rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bfjeo.png)

I am entering data using VBA into SQL server.  The code works fine.
I am using SQL Server 2014.  The database is located on my server. these computers have a secured, authenticated remote access to my machine/server?  Users are entering in the information via an Excel .xlsm file.

This is the problem.  I am sending my Excel/VBA .xlsm file to other people logged into different computers.

When they try to enter information on different computers, the code does not work.

The code only works when I use my computer which has my database on it.

How can I modify my connection string so that it works on other computers?  I have tried many different connections, but nothing works.

```
Private Sub Click()


Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

Dim strconn As String

strconn = "Driver={SQL Server}; Server=DESKTOP-MyServer; Database = Test; User ID = myid; Password = mypassword;"

cn.Open strconn
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
MsgBox "Connection Works!"


End Sub
```

The VBA error message that I receive is the following:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist
or access denied.
```

Comment: It looks like you enabled TCP IP only for the local loopback address (127.0.0.1). Enable TCP IP on the other interfaces too and restart the SQL Server service.

Comment: You added the port only on one IP address.  Set "Listen All" to true, and configure the port on IPAll, not IP5.

Answer (score 1):

To access a SQL Server from a network client, you must

1) [Configure SQL Server to Listen on TCP/IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port).  The easiest configuration is to have SQL listen on the default port (1433).

2) [Configure the Windows Firewall to allow inbound connections to SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access).

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comment David.  I have added new comments and pictures at the very top of my original post.